# Jquery Inputmask saving wrong monetary value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I'm trying to save a monetary value  with InputMask like this `1000.5 -> 1.000,50`

This is my code for the InputMask

```
var mmoney = new Inputmask('decimal', {
            autoUnmask: true,
            unmaskAsNumber: true,
            groupSeparator: '.',
            radixPoint: ",",
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: false,
            rightAlign: false });
if($('.msk-money').length) {
    mmoney.mask($(".msk-money"));
}
```

but insted saving 1000.5 are saving 1.0005. How I remove the mask to save in database?

Comment: Why not use the Intl to format the way you want? new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(1000.5)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are getting the value. The autoMask should take care of it if you use `.val()`.  It may not work if you are using default submit behavior.

you can do this:

```
$(selector).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
```

But, it's likely that you are setting the initial value of to "1.000,50".  If you set the initial value to the formatted version, it won't recognize it. Be sure to set the initial value as a decimal so that you can later retrieve it.